# How can I use reduceByKey for RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, reduce

I have a RDD:

```
[{'date': '27/07/2022', 'user': 'User_83031', 'number_of_emails': 96},
 {'date': '27/07/2022', 'user': 'User_45839', 'number_of_emails': 110},
 {'date': '14/12/2022', 'user': 'User_15817', 'number_of_emails': 49}]
```

The code is:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName = "app-name")
raw_data=sc.textFile("emails.txt")
def formatEmail (row):
    return {
        "date": row.split(',')[0],
        "user": row.split(',')[1], 
        "number_of_emails": int(row.split(',')[2])
    }

emailsRDD=raw_data.map(lambda r: formatEmail(r))
emailsRDD.take(3)`
```

I run into problem when I try to use `reduceByKey`.

```py
test=emailsRDD.map(lambda x: (x.get("date"),1)) \
  .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
test.first()`
```

The output is give me an error:

```
ValueError: RDD is empty
```

Does anybody knows why the error is occurred?

I am expecting to get paired RDD with date as a key and the value is the number of key occurences, like below:

```
('27/07/2022', 2)
```

Comment: Can you check if raw_data is empty or not?

Comment: I checked it: 
raw_data.take(5)

The output:
['27/07/2022,User_83031,96',
 '27/07/2022,User_45839,110',
 '14/12/2022,User_15817,49',
 '17/08/2022,User_56095,54',
 '27/04/2021,User_97952,106']

Comment: Why do you need to use RDD API?

Answer (score 0):

It's very inefficient to use RDD with Python. Really, in 2023rd you should use [DataFrame API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) that is more efficient.  Plus you get things like, loading data as CSV file instead of manually parsing your lines.

With DataFrame API code will look as following:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.read.csv("emails.txt", schema="date string, user string, num int")
df2 = df.groupBy("date").agg(F.sum("num"))
df2.show()
```

will give you as expected:

```
+----------+--------+
|      date|sum(num)|
+----------+--------+
|27/04/2021|     106|
|17/08/2022|      54|
|14/12/2022|      49|
|27/07/2022|     206|
+----------+--------+
```

In this case you work with high-level constructs, like:

- loading data as CSV using the `spark.read.csv`
- Summarizing your data for each `date` occurrence

Such code is much easier to read, plus it's more efficient as Spark won't need to serialize/deserialize data between JVM and Python.